# How to know in which fonts a specific glyph is available?

Tags: font-recommendation, glyphs

I am looking for free serif fonts containing a glyph for the [`U+202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Width_variation) (i.e. a non-breaking thin space).

A [Palatino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatino)-style font would do fine.
I already checked [TeX Gyre Pagella](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/) but the non-breaking thin space glyphs fails.

Comment: What do you consider to be *properly defined?* If it’s just that the glyph should actually exist and have roughly half the width of the *space* glyph and you have no further constraints on the font, then this question is far too broad (and you will find an answer that will probably not satisfy you on my profile).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I edited the question according to your recommendations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Over at [FileFormat.info](https://www.fileformat.info/) «The Digital Rosetta Stone», I found a handy [unicode character search engine](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm).

On the resulting page, click on the [Fonts that support U+202F](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202f/fontsupport.htm) link, and there you have it.

The serif fonts include:

- [Cambria](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/cambria/index.htm)
- [Cardo](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/cardo/index.htm)
- [DejaVu Serif](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/dejavu_serif/index.htm)
- [Doulos SIL](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/doulos_sil/index.htm)
- [FreeSerif](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/freeserif/index.htm)
- [Jomolhari](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/jomolhari/index.htm)
- [JunicodeRegular](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/junicoderegular/index.htm)
- [LeedsUni](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/leedsuni/index.htm)
- [Liberation Serif](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/liberation_serif/index.htm)
- [Linux Libertine](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/linux_libertine/index.htm)
- [Microsoft Sans Serif](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/microsoft_sans_serif/index.htm)
- [Quivra](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/quivira/index.htm)
- [Symbola](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/symbola/index.htm)
- [Times New Roman](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/times_new_roman/index.htm)
- [Tinos](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/tinos/index.htm)

Comment: I just tried this method and when I searched the character 好 in https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm , 1 hit was found, I clicked on that result and the button "Fonts that support U+597D
" was shown with this URL: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/597d/index.htm . When I searched the character , 0 hits were found, so I couldn't jump to the result, therefore I wasn't shown the button "Fonts that support U+2E932".  To solve this, I edited the previously URL, to have the hexadecimal code of  https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2E932/index.htm

Answer (score 5):

To determine which locally installed fonts contain a specific glyph on open-source systems like Linux and BSD that use [Fontconfig](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/), the `fc-list` command can be used as follows:

```
fc-list ':charset=202f'
```

Where `202f` is the code point of the character you want to find.

Answer (score 0):

To check the glyphs available in fonts which you have on your system, there are many ways.

To do it manually in a GUI on a Mac, you can use the character viewer, in which you can search by Unicode codepoint (in your case, type `U+202F` in the search box).

There are also command-line tools which you can install to search all your fonts on Mac, Linux or Windows. For example, you could use `ttx`, a "[command to convert binary font files (.otf, .ttf, etc) to the TTX XML format](https://fonttools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ttx.html#ttx-from-opentype-and-truetype-to-xml-and-back)" and search your character in it's output.

On a Mac you can install it with `brew install fonttools` if you already have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). On a Debian system or other derivatives like Ubuntu, you can `apt install fonttools`.

Then you can grep the output to find your character in a font file, with something like this :

```
ttx -o - -t cmap "/path/to/some_font.ttf" | grep '0x202f' >/dev/null
```

You can wrap that in a loop to check all your font files. The following command on my Linux system searches for fonts in my fonts directory, uses ttx to print out an XML version, and searches that for the wanted character. If the code point was found, it gets the font name with `otfinfo` and prints it with the file name :

```
find /usr/share/fonts -iname "*.otf" -o -iname "*.ttf" | while read f; do ttx -o - -t cmap "$f" | grep '0x202f' >/dev/null && printf "%-35s %s\n" $(otfinfo -p "$f") "$f"; done | sort
```

Or the same on multiple lines to make it (slightly) more readable:

```
find /usr/share/fonts -iname "*.otf" -o -iname "*.ttf" \
| while read f; do
      ttx -o - -t cmap "$f" \
      | grep '0x202f' >/dev/null \
        && printf "%-35s %s\n" $(otfinfo -p "$f") "$f"
  done \
| sort
```

This is the output on my system for your `U+202F` character :

```
AbyssinicaSIL                       /usr/share/fonts/truetype/abyssinica/AbyssinicaSIL-R.ttf
Consolas-BoldItalic                 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/consolas-win7/consolaz.ttf
Consolas-Bold                       /usr/share/fonts/truetype/consolas-win7/consolab.ttf
Consolas-Italic                     /usr/share/fonts/truetype/consolas-win7/consolai.ttf
Consolas                            /usr/share/fonts/truetype/consolas-win7/consola.ttf
DejaVuSans-BoldOblique              /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf
DejaVuSans-Bold                     /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique     /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique.ttf
DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold            /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf
DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique         /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf
DejaVuSansCondensed                 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf
DejaVuSans-ExtraLight               /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-ExtraLight.ttf
DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique          /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf
DejaVuSansMono-Bold                 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf
DejaVuSansMono-Oblique              /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf
DejaVuSansMono                      /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
DejaVuSans-Oblique                  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf
DejaVuSans                          /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf
DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic              /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
DejaVuSerif-Bold                    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf
DejaVuSerifCondensed-BoldItalic     /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf
DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold           /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold.ttf
DejaVuSerifCondensed-Italic         /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed-Italic.ttf
DejaVuSerifCondensed                /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf
DejaVuSerif-Italic                  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf
DejaVuSerif                         /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf
FontAwesome                         /usr/share/fonts/truetype/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
FreeMonoBoldOblique                 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeMonoBoldOblique.ttf
FreeMonoBold                        /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeMonoBold.ttf
FreeMonoOblique                     /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeMonoOblique.ttf
FreeMono                            /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeMono.ttf
FreeSansBoldOblique                 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSansBoldOblique.ttf
FreeSansBold                        /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSansBold.ttf
FreeSansOblique                     /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSansOblique.ttf
FreeSans                            /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSans.ttf
FreeSerifBoldItalic                 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerifBoldItalic.ttf
FreeSerifBold                       /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerifBold.ttf
FreeSerifItalic                     /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerifItalic.ttf
FreeSerif                           /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf
Lato-BlackItalic                    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-BlackItalic.ttf
Lato-Black                          /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Black.ttf
Lato-BoldItalic                     /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-BoldItalic.ttf
Lato-Bold                           /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Bold.ttf
Lato-HairlineItalic                 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-HairlineItalic.ttf
Lato-Hairline                       /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Hairline.ttf
Lato-HeavyItalic                    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-HeavyItalic.ttf
Lato-Heavy                          /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Heavy.ttf
Lato-Italic                         /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Italic.ttf
Lato-LightItalic                    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-LightItalic.ttf
Lato-Light                          /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Light.ttf
Lato-MediumItalic                   /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-MediumItalic.ttf
Lato-Medium                         /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Medium.ttf
Lato-Regular                        /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Regular.ttf
Lato-SemiboldItalic                 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-SemiboldItalic.ttf
Lato-Semibold                       /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Semibold.ttf
Lato-ThinItalic                     /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-ThinItalic.ttf
Lato-Thin                           /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Thin.ttf
Symbola                             /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ancient-scripts/Symbola_hint.ttf
Tibetan_Machine_Uni                 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/tibetan-machine/TibetanMachineUni.ttf
```

(The `otfinfo` tool used to also print the normal name of the font can be installed with `brew install lcdf-typetools` or `apt install lcdf-typetools`, etc. depending on your system)